# i'm trying to put a manipulated image to welcome people on my dicrod bo using jimp

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, jimp

I'm using this but it's not working. I don't know why please help me.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const jimp = require("jimp");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require("./config.json");

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Bot foi iniciado`)
});

client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member => {

    let canal = client.channels.get("750795877089804309")
    let fonte = await jimp.loadFont(jimp.FONT_SANS_32_BLACK)
    let mask = await jimp.read('mascara.png')
    let fundo = await jimp.read('fundo.png')

    jimp.read(member.user.defaultAvatarURL).then(avatar => {
            avatar.resize(400, 400)
            mask.resize(400, 400)
            fundo.resize(270, 190)
            avatar.mask(mask)
            fundo.print(fonte, 05, 120, member.user.username)
            avatar.composite(fundo, 80, 170).write('resultado.png')
            canal.send(``, {
                files: ["resultado.png"]
            })

            console.log('imagem enviada')
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Deu erro aqui porra')
        });

});

client.on("message", async message => {

    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.channel.type === "dm") return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const comando = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (comando === "ping") {
        const m = await message.channel.send("Sifude");
        m.edit(`A Latência é ${m.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms. A Latencia da API é ${Math.round(client.ping)}ms`);
    }

});

client.login(config.token);
```

Comment: Please describe any errors or warnings you're getting. What's the expected behaviour?

Comment: oh sorry, it's saying that client.channel.get is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
let canal = client.channels.cache.get("750795877089804309")
```

As client.channels return a ChannelManager object and not a collection.